# Difference between dozed off and slept?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning, word-difference

Is there any difference between sleep and doze off?
I have always used dozed off to imply that I slept unintentionally or lightly like for example

> The lecture was so boring that I dozed off in the class.
>   I missed my stop as I dozed off in the bus.

Is this how we use "doze off"? Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say it with the past perfect:

> I missed my stop as I **had dozed off** on the bus.

**as** means "because".  **had dozen off** = had fallen asleep. You were already fully asleep when the bus arrived at your stop.

Without the past perfect, using simple past:

> I missed my stop as I **dozed off** on the bus.

**as** means "while".  dozed off = fell asleep.  You were falling asleep *just when* you should have been preparing to get off the bus.

Answer (score 2):

"Doze off" means you fall asleep without meaning to, or without actively trying to do.

Both your examples are correct usage of the term.